# Finding messageID of Pub/Sub message triggering Cloud Function

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to access messageId of the Pub/Sub message triggering my Golang function. To do so, I'm trying to modify the PubSubMessage struct from the [Cloud Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions_calling_pubsub-go):

```
// PubSubMessage is the payload of a Pub/Sub event.
// See the documentation for more details:
// https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage
type PubSubMessage struct {
        Data []byte `json:"data"`
        MessageId string `json:"messageId"`
}
```

The function compiles OK but the MessageID value comes empty. Changing the type doesn't help.
I wonder if there's a way to get the triggering message Id from within a function. Or maybe that's not passed to functions at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the document you refer,

> **Event structure**
>
> Cloud Functions triggered from a Pub/Sub topic will be
> sent events conforming to the PubsubMessage type, with the caveat that
> **publishTime and messageId are not directly available in the
> PubsubMessage**. Instead, you can access publishTime and messageId via
> the event ID and timestamp properties of the event metadata. This
> metadata is accessible via the context object that is passed to your
> function when it is invoked.

You can get `messageId` like this.

```
import  "cloud.google.com/go/functions/metadata"

func YourFunc(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    metadata, err := metadata.FromContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle Error
    }
    messageId := metadata.EventID

    // Rest of your code below here.
}
```

Comment: There's no `EventId` field in the metadata structure, but works with `EventID` 

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Fixed my answer.

Comment: TIL how to do that. Thanks, again! 